# Show activity after dialog closes without reseting

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-view, android-dialog

I am trying to show a new activity after my dialog disappears. everything works fine, but i dont know how to go fra dialog to activity, without reseting the activity.

i have something like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
```

But this just reset the MainActivity. Anyone who can help explaining me how i can show my MainActivity without reseting the information on the MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

No need to start the activity again, just [dismiss the dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()):

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Or from dialog class itself, just call `dismiss();`.

Comment: I am dismissing the dialog, and showing my MainActivity, but the FLAGS are reseting the view. I have 2 fragments, fragment 1 is my MainActivity and Fragment 2 is where i call the dialog. when the dialog dissapear i want to show fragment 1, but without resetting.

Comment: It is not connected with dialog itself. Basically you need to perfrom [`popBackStack()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()).

Comment: i am trying to do something like this, but still not working.

     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_top_fragment, new MainScreenFragment());
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Perform `replace()` and then `addToBackStack()`, not vice versa.

Comment: changed as you said

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_top_fragment, new MainScreenFragment());
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: I have added this code in my first fragment 

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_central_fragment, new Option1Page(), Option1Page.class.getName())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

and this code in my second fragment inside the dialog when user clicks yes 

 getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

and it is still not working

Comment: Your current question has no relatance with your actual issue. Either update your question, or create a new question.

Comment: but you introduced me to popBackStack, the only thing i am trying to do, is to get back to first fragment after user clicks yes button inside an alertDialog.